# What exactly is narrowing type conversion in java?

Tags: java, narrowing

According to my knowledge in Java, in narrowing type conversion if source in any constant which is in range of byte than the following is allowed:

```
byte b=10; // allowed because 10 is in range of byte and 10 is a constant
```

but when I type this:

```
byte b=10l; // this is not allowed although 10 is in range of byte and is a constant
```

Why so ?
Can you please tell the exact rule by which these narrowing conversions take place in Java.

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=260

Comment: AFAIK this is a ["narrowing *primitive* conversion"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6627911/2864740) (e.g. `byte b = 10`) and not a "narrowing *type* conversion" (e.g. `(byte)10`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical answer is — because the spec says so. [§5.2 "Assignment Contexts" of *The Java Language Specification*, Java SE 8 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), states in part:

> In addition, if the expression [on the right-hand-side of an assignment statement] is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

As for why it doesn't allow the constant expression to be of type `long`, I suppose it's that you never "accidentally" end up in type `long`. It is very convenient to be able to write `byte b = 127` as a shorthand for `byte b = (byte) 127` while having the compiler prevent you from erroneously writing `byte b = 128` as shorthand for `byte b = (byte) 128`; it is not so useful to able to write `byte b = 127L`, specifically, because why would you need that?

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>   type **byte, short, char, or int**:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is **byte, short, or char**, and the value of the constant
>     expression is representable in the type of the variable.

You have a constant expression of type long and the narrowing primitive conversion can't be applied in that case.

So you can do:

- `byte b = 10`
- `byte b = (int) 10`
- `char b = (short) 10`
- `byte b = (char) 10L`
- `short b = (int) 10L`

But you can't do:

- `byte b = 10L`
- `byte b = (long) 10`

Answer (score 1):

because the `l` you attached to value tells the compiler  explicitly  - "listen bro. I've a 'long' field here. Give it space required for a 'long' field".

Obviously  a long value cannot fit in into a byte field.
So, you get the error - `Cannot Convert from Long to Byte`

Comment: But in byte b=10, 10 will be treated as int and its size is 4 times the size of byte. Then, your argument should be true in that case also.

Comment: @VikasMangal The "narrowing primitive conversion" is only applied up-to `int` (not `long`) compile-time constant values.

Comment: Note that "field" has a technical sense in Java (it refers to a member variable), so you might want to select a different term.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strongly typed language. it implicitely handles type conversion from smaller types to Bigger types but in case of type conversions from Bigger Type to smaller type you need to do it explicitly by type casting.

For example a long can accomodate int but an int can not have sufficient space to accomodate longs so compiler warns you.

So in your case you can do:

```
byte b= (byte) 10l;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You can also do `byte b = (int) 10l` and `int` is "bigger" than `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, 10 is in range of byte. But when you use `l` suffix with constant, java understands it that this constant is `long`. Because `long` can't fit into a `byte`, you get an error: possible loss of precision, being said by javac.

However, `byte b = (byte) 10l;` works, because it is a straight cast from `long` to `byte`.

Comment: In java, every literal integer can be of type `byte`, `short`, `int`, or `long`. By default Java try to assing integer to the variable, assuming integer fits in variable's type size. If it won't fit, compiler raises an error. When you write `byte b = 10`, it is fine, because 10 fits in byte and is treated as byte. However, if you try `byte b = 130`, you'll get the same error, because 130 isn't in `byte` range.